# Azure Webjob ERROR: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (appname.deps.json) was not found

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I published a webjob on Azure -> [Visual Studio 2019 - Adding WebJob project in WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895100/visual-studio-2019-adding-webjob-project-in-webapp) but now it shows this error:

[image]

The webJob is developed in netcore 2.2

Comment: Have you already install the package `Abp.AutoMapper` in your app? And have you check whether there are files under this path?

Comment: Can you provide the type of app you created?

Comment: Please try to deploy whole your webjob project with VS 2019 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs